# How do I create a List<T> from a SortedList<int, T>?

Tags: .net, list, sortedlist

I'm working with .net 3.5, and I have this:

```
SortedList<int, BrainTickTransition>
```

And I want one of these:

```
List<BrainTickTransition>
```

Is there a quick way to do this without having to copy all of the values from the SortedList?

Comment: Consider the SortedList.Values property.

Comment: I have a datacontract that serializes a List<BrainTickTransition>, which is why I need the List<T>.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The values need to be copied, because there is no way to share the memory between a `List<TValue>` and a `SortedList<TKey,TValue>`.

I assume you want a `List<TValue>` containing the values without caring about the keys, which you can do with:

```
sortedList.Values.ToList();
```

But if you just need an `IList<TValue>` (as opposed to the concrete class `List<TValue>`) you can directly use the [`Values`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132380.aspx) property and thus avoid creating a copy.

Of course these solutions differ in their semantic when the original collection gets modified. The `List<TValue>` copy will not reflect the changes, whereas the `IList<TValue>` referenced by the `Values` property, will reflect the changes, even if you assign it to another variable.

Comment: Looks like that's it, thanks. Answer accepted after timer runs out. :)

Comment: Poor, poor `new List<TValue>(sortedList.Values)`. Noone wants to play with it anymore. :-)

Answer (score 2):

**This Works:**

```
myList = new List<string>(mySortedList.Values);
```

(Credit to the comment by @Jon). 
The `new List` will never see subsequent changes to the sortedList. This is perfect **for a scenario where SortedList was just for temp usage, or where the Sorted is for historic reference**.

However, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8438871/2381899) by @CodesInChaos doesn't
 **Does Not Work**:

```
myList = mySortedList.Values.ToList();
```

ToList() fails with with exception: `IList<string> does not contain a definition for ToList`